# What does the time reversibility of the laws of physics mean for causality?

Tags: time, causality, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

Does the fact that the fundamental laws are symmetric with respect to direction of time show that causation does not exist? Since causality always requires the cause to precede the effect, but laws of physics do not care about which direction time flows.

Does this mean there is no place for causality in (modern) physics? This is based on an argument of Russell's and goes like this:

• Causality is time asymmetric
• Laws of physics are time symmetric
-> There is no (fundamental) notion of cause in physics

Is this correct? Could anyone suggest some articles/papers about this?

In this video the problem is presented: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AMCcYnAsdQ

Comment: The fundamental laws, or, more precisely, the predictions of the standard model, are *not* symmetric under time reversal. This follows from the CPT theorem and experimental evidence for CP violation. However, it is not clear if this has anything to do with the so-called arrow of time.

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=kIq5CZlg8Rg

Comment: I would ignore minute physics, I've seen too many misleading or wrong claims from them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "Causality" the equivalent of a claim that the future is predictable based on the present and the past?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34749)